# Как переписать функцию. Из стрелочной в обычную. Именованную

Tags: javascript

```js
    const newPost = (post, addedAt = Date()) => ({
        ...post,
        addedAt,
    })
    const firstPost = {
        id: 1,
        author: 'Denis'
    }
    console.log(newPost(firstPost))
```

Расскажите пожалуйста как преобразовать функцию (стрелочную) в (именованную). Борюсь с этим уже 2 дня, а всё никак.

---

Моя попытка преобразования из примера выше, понимаю, что не так, но для этого я и тут, что бы впитывать знания.

```
function newPost() {
    addedAt = Date()
    return newPost
}
const firstPost = {
    id: 1,
    author: 'Denis'
}
newPost()
```

Comment: И что за 2 дня смогли сделать? В чем проблема возникла

Comment: Вообще результат Date() выводит - нынешнюю дату и время, остальное не получается

Comment: id и author не показывает в выводе функции

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример, что вы сделали и что не получается

Comment: Не понимаю принцип изменения функций. Изучаю программирование неделю только, поэтому пока все сложно, на первых парах. Сейчас напишу

Comment: Как вы до стрелочных функций добрались не изучив обычные? Тем не менее, отредактируйте вопрос и  покажите вашу попытку решения

Comment: @SwaD, по примерам :)

Comment: @UModeL Уже нет... Хотя ответ, конечно, был готов )

Comment: function newPost() {
    addedAt = Date()
    return newPost
}
const firstPost = {
    id: 1,
    author: 'Denis'
}
newPost()

Comment: Обычные функции я прошел и вроде проблем не возникает, но вот вопрос с преобразованием ставит в тупик

Comment: @ДенисЧикасов, преобразование из одной в другую, при условии отсутствия использования `arguments` или `this` - тривиально. `=>` убирается, добавляется ключевое слово `function` с именем (опционально) в теле, если отсутствует - добавляется `return`

Comment: @ДенисЧикасов, у тебя какая-то странная попытка. Потерял параметры, потеря тело функции

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться\

Comment: @ДенисЧикасов, добавил еще один дубликат - в нем понятнее должно быть